# Uncaught ReferenceError: changeValue is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, combobox, displayobject

I have a code, the code previously run smoothly and can display data in etxtbox from combobox. after a change of the contents of the data in the database can keep ComboBox from the database, but after the select does not want to show in the textbox.

```
    <?php
    $result = mysql_query("select * from cab_ccf");  
    $jsArray = "var prdName = new Array();\n";  
        echo '<select name="prdId" onchange="changeValue(this.value)">';  
        echo '<option>-------</option>';  
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
                echo '<option value="' . $row['cabkode'] . '">' . $row['cabnama'] . '</option>';  
                $jsArray .= "prdName['" . $row['cabkode'] . "'] = {name:'" . addslashes($row['wa_pial']) . "',desc:'".addslashes($row['cabalamat'])."'};\n";
            }  
        echo '</select>';  
?>  
 <tr>
    <td width="200px;">Nama</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="tNama" id="prd_name" style="border:none; background-color:#F5F5DC;" readonly/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="200px;">Pekerjaan / Jabatan</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="tWapil" value="Wakil Pialang" style="border:none; background-color:#F5F5DC;" readonly/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="200px;">Alamat</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td> <textarea type="text" name="nasalamat" name="tAlamat" id="prd_desc" cols="46" rows="3"  style="border:none; background-color:#F5F5DC;" readonly></textarea></td>
</tr>
<script type="text/javascript">  
    <?php echo $jsArray; ?>  
    function changeValue(id){  
        document.getElementById('prd_name').value = prdName[id].name;  
        document.getElementById('prd_desc').value = prdName[id].desc;  
    }; 
</script>
```

error message is Uncaught ReferenceError: changeValue is not defined, after change database im not change anything about the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    var prdName = new Array();
prdName['cab0001'] = {name:'Danny Alfian',desc:'The Plaza Office Tower, Jl. MH. Thamrin Kav. 28-30, Jakarta 10350'};
prdName['cab0002'] = {name:'Yandri M Nova',desc:'Komplek Perkantoran Delta Blok 3-F, Jl. Juanda, Medan, Sumatra Utara'};
prdName['cab0003'] = {name:'Ridhwan',desc:'The Royal Condominium Tower A,Ground Floor Suite 01, Jl. Palang Merah, Medan, Sumatra Utara 20151'};
prdName['cab0004'] = {name:'Khrisna Dwi Hendriyanto',desc:'Graha SA Office Building Ground Floor
Jl. Raya Gubeng 19-21, Surabaya 60281, Jawa Timur'};
prdName['cab0005'] = {name:'Indah Ratnaningtyas',desc:'Jl. Magelang KM 4 No. 188, Sleman Yogyakarta 55284'};
prdName['cab0006'] = {name:'A. A. Gede Mars Adi C',desc:'Jl. Jend Ahmad Yani KM 3,5 No. 3, Banjarmasin, Kalimantan Selatan'};
prdName['cab0007'] = {name:'Mardi Milono',desc:'Jl. Arifin Ahmad No. 90D, Tangkerang Tengah Marpoyan Damai - pekanbaru Riau'};
prdName['cab0008'] = {name:'Gatot Suseno',desc:'Jl. Ahmad Yani No. 267, Bandung, Jawa Barat'};
prdName['cab0009'] = {name:'Nurkamid',desc:'Jl. Veteran 65, Semarang 50231, Jawa Tengah'};
prdName['cab0010'] = {name:'Denny Sundawa PK',desc:'Jl. Semeru No. 60, Malang 65112, Jawa Timur'};
prdName['cab0011'] = {name:'Ahmad Haya',desc:'Jl. Panjaitan No. 88, Purwokerto, Jawa Tengah'};

    function changeValue(id){  
        document.getElementById('prd_name').value = prdName[id].name;  
        document.getElementById('prd_desc').value = prdName[id].desc;  
    }; 
</script>
```

Comment: is there any other error in your browser console...

Comment: The `select` doesnt have the value, just check it's options selected index

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL and Uncaught ReferenceError: changeValue is not defined
just 2